# Inserting a record in the middle of a set of records in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Say, I have 10 records in my MS Access file. I need to insert few rows inside i.e: in the middle of existing records. How to do that? Any suggestions?
Regards

Comment: What you mean by "in the middle of existing records"

Comment: incomplete and vague question :s

Comment: Records in a database should have no inherent order, unless you specify one for a given request. Presumably you have some sort of ordering in mind - last name/first name, date - so inserting records in the middle is just a matter of finding the appropriate values to insert in the fields you want to order by.

Answer (score 2):

Ordering of table records is insignificant - it is database engine's responsibility to make sure that records are stored in an efficient manner, no matter in which order!

You can always retrieve data in a certain order by using query language.

Answer (score 0):

**Example to insert data**

```
INSERT INTO tblCustomers 
VALUES (1, Kelly, 'Jill', '555-1040', 'someone@microsoft.com')
```

refrence From  [Harald Brinkhof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419586/harald-brinkhof)

> The order of inserting data in a database is inconsequential, what is
>   important is the order of retrieval which you manipulate by the ORDER
>   BY substatement you provide your SELECT statement with.

So you'll need to identify the field by which you can order things,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblCustomers 
ORDER BY email_address ASC;
```